# Sharepoint nodejs upload file

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to upload a file to the SharePoint shared folder.
I am able to upload a file using [spsave](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spsave) but its uploading to the Files location. I would like to upload to the Shared location instead of Files location. Doing it in this way:

```
  const fileOptions = {
  folder: '/Documents/testing',
  fileName: 'test.txt',
  fileContent: 'hello world'
};
```

it's uploading to the `Files` location under testing folder I can see the file `text.txt`. Can't figure it out how to upload to the Shared folder. Is this possible? Can't find the related path for the shared destination. For Files it's `Documents` but what would be for the Shared??? Anyone have any knowledge about sharepoint onedrive and could help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can upload to OneDrive with spsave. It is for native SharePoint only afaik. If you want to share a file in OneDrive using a rest api I suggest to look at office graph.